# Type Safety warning when casting to generic class in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I have a class

```
class Property<T> {
    value T;

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now I have a list `List<Property<?>> properties` with various properties of various Types. I loop through this list and want to set the value of every Property. Therefore I need to cast the generic Property to the correct type like:
e.g. for Integer:

```
if (property.getType().equals("Integer")) {
        Property<Integer> propInt = (Property<Integer>) property;
        propInt.setValue((Integer) values[i++]);
}
```

where `values[]` is an Object array which holds the values that I want to set.

Everything works fine, but Java complains about Type Safety "Unchecked cast from `Property<?>` to `Property<Integer>`". A check like

```
if (property instanceof Property<Integer>){...}
```

is not possible though.
How can I change my code to get rid of this warning, or do you know a better practice for my case?

Comment: You should reconsider your design, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler complains because `property` is of type `Property<?>` which could or could not be of type `Property<Integer>` in general. This is an inherent limitation of the current java language due to type erasure.

In this particular case you are making sure that `property` is of class `Property<Integer>` by use of the `getType` method so it is safe to ignore the warning.

```
if (property.getType().equals("Integer")) {
        // we have made sure property is of class Property<Integer> so the cast is type safe
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Property<Integer> propInt = (Property<Integer>) property;
        propInt.setValue((Integer) values[i++]);
}
```

It is important to document it with a comment otherwise a peer reviewing your code might not notice that indeed the cast is type safe and could confuse the warning supression as a malpractice.

Answer (score 2):

#### If you are using the spring framework, you can also use:

```
import static org.springframework.data.util.CastUtils.cast;
```

```
        Map<String,Object> messageMap = cast(exchange.getMessage().getBody());
        List<String> refIds = cast(messageMap.get("refIds"));
```

#### Note:

I wouldn't suggest using this unless the spring framework is already part of your application.

Comment: I just opened the implementation and copied it. Thanks, very helpful. I can add to your answer: just use this function, if you are sure that the casting done is the right cast.

Answer (score 0):

The warning indicates, that at source level, the list may contain objects of any type () and you cast those to Integer, which would lead to a ClassCastException at runtime, in cases where the list contains a non-Integer object. So the warning indicates a potential problem at runtime.

You could get rid of the warning by either

- declaring the List as List of Integers `List<Integer>`
- or, suppress the warning using the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the method or the list declaration.

If you can not guarantee, that the objects contained in the list are no Integer, then you should have the `instanceof` before the cast and the SuppressWarning. If you can guarantee it, then you should declare the list as list of Integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `annotation SuppressWarnings` to ignore this warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Property<Integer> propInt = (Property<Integer>) property;
```

but it's a risk to do this.

this warning is caused by ***type erasure***, because when compile, ***generic type*** will be erased.

Answer (score 0):

As you know generics in java suffer a bit from type erasure, all becomes Object at run-time.

As you test on strings like "Integer", it would seem adding a `Class<T>` could even be convenient.

```
class Property<T> {
    final Class<T> type;
    value T;

    public Property(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setAnyValue(Object value) {
        this.value = type.cast(value);
    }
}

Property<?> property = ...
//if (property.getType() == Integer.class) {
//    Property<Integer> propInt = (Property<Integer>) property;
//    propInt.setAnyValue((Integer) values[i++]);
//}
property.setAnyValue(values[i++]);
```

The usage of Object is due to the **polymorph** usage of Property instead of the more normal typing: your code mixes up differently typed properties and parallel values.

Comment: it is a little far stretched when people say that it is erased entirely at runtime; erasure indeed happens, but not entirely. there are two things in byte code : `descriptor` of a method (entirely erased) and `Signature` (entirely not erased). Think about it, if a certain code would be stripped of all it's generic code after compilation, how would the callers know that a certain method is generic? Or how `checkcast` would be inserted into the bytecode for the callers? where would information be taken from?

Comment: or simpler, I have a class that has a method `public void add(List<Integer> list)`, I compile it and give it to you. When you use it, does it mean that you can actually call it with `add(List.of(new Object()))`?

Comment: @Eugene I think the comments are valuable. I will not comment them though as java started with full type erasure, but meanwhile it seems that typing is in the make. Maybe with Valhalla's value types: `List<int>`. Tricks such as mine or `list.toArray(new Integer[0])` will then be obsolete.

Comment: that actually was the only reason I choose to comment under your answer instead of so many here on SO; I was really wondering if you might know if there was ever a compiler that did not generate the `Signature` field, thus generics were *really* erased...